# How to display validation errors on form submit

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple form with only input field name, email. On my view page, I have form where customer's email can be entered and saved in ajax way. This is my view page:

_form.html.erb

```
   <%= form_for @customer, :remote=>true do |f| %>
       <div id="errors"></div>
        <%= f.text_field :email, :maxlength => 30, :placeholder => "Email", :id => "ecustomer" %>
        <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
   <% end %>
```

This is my create.js.erb

```
  <% if @customer.errors.any? -%>
    $('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "error", :locals => {:target => @customer })%>').appendTo('#errors')
  <% else -%>
    $("<%= escape_javascript(render @customer) %>").prependTo("table.table.customers tbody");
  <% end -%>
```

I have put validation of presence and uniqueness on email. And for displaying validation error, i have partial, _error.erb:

```
 <div class="alert alert-error">
  <h5><%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h5>

  <ul>
  <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But still my validation errors are not visible. I am not getting whats going wrong here. Can anybody help me how to get it work?

Thank you.

Comment: Code seems oke, what does the controller look like? Try putting a JS try-catch block around the code to trace the errors.. Remotely added JS won't show errors..

Comment: @Tim can you tell how to add JS try-catch block? I am not aware of it. Thanks.

Comment: Added an answer with the block..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Try-Catch block to your JS view:

```
<% if @customer.errors.any? -%>
  try {
    $('<%= j(render :partial => "error", :locals => {:target => @customer })%>').appendTo('#errors');
  } catch( e ) {
    console.log( e );
  }
<% else -%>
  try {
    $("<%= j(render @customer) %>").prependTo("table.table.customers tbody");
  } catch( e ) {
    console.log( e );
  }
<% end -%>
```

If the block doesn't log, you're probably dealing with a syntax error.